# Stroke research question - has there been research in mirroring muscle electrical signals from a good limb to the bad one?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology, electrical-stimulation

Transcutaneous electrical neural stimulation is an established tool to help stroke victims recover use of a paralyzed limb by engaging neuroplasticity. Has anyone here heard of research where you wear sensors on a good limb and mirror the signals from the good limb to the bad one as a sort of electrical mirroring? My search has been fruitless and I wanted to see if anyone knows of anything before I engage this further.

Comment: I would understand better what the benefit was if the same electrodes were the same on both sides, because they can already send electrical signals to one limb naturally and effect their own mirroring as a result.

Comment: Imagine the left arm is bad and the right arm is good. As the patient lives out his daily life and moves the right arm, sensors pick up the motion and send it to stimulators on the left arm, hence mirroring. The idea is to leverage activity in the brain for the right arm to create an association for the left arm.

Comment: What were your search phrases? You'd probably need to search the physical therapy literature. I'd start with *physical therapy post stroke TENS* and look for terms to narrow the field.